# neato laser stop

Tags: ros, laser, neato

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the neato laser running on my turtlebot2 using the Kobuki base. As soon as turtlebot boots up and the laser receives power from the on board computer via the usb port, it starts spinning. I would like to control the laser startup where I can turn it on only when needed like during gmapping or slam or when running minimal launch. I would like to turn off the laser when I'm not using slam or mapping or when I'm just charging the base.
What is/are the ROS recommended ways of doing this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271780/neato-laser-stop/) by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the neato hardware supports this. In my experience, the neato lidar starts spinning as soon as you apply power.

If you have a third-party controller board for your Neato, you may be able to use it to turn power on and off for your Neato.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-28**:
I have the controller board from Get surreal. I'm looking to controller is via software. I may look into turning the power off on the usb port (ACM0 in my case). The board has a button that turns off the power but it doesnt turn it back on like a toggle switch.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-28**:
According the [this GetSurreal page](https://www.getsurreal.com/product/xv-lidar-controller-v1-2?v=47e5dceea252) the controller has motor on and off commands, but I don't see anything in the [neato driver](https://github.com/rohbotics/xv_11_laser_driver) that would send those commands.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-28**:
You will probably need to modify the neato driver to send the on and off commands from a ROS service, or when the node starts and stops.

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-29**:
Thank you ahendrix!

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-29**:
I havent written or modified any drivers before. I may look into it.